# Use view with or without assigning it to variable

Tags: java, android, view

Since I don't understand much from what's happening in the background (or I am too lazy to learn and remember) I've got this pretty simple question.
If i take, for example, assigning text to TextView, I've got two options from what I know:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.random_id)).setText("random text");
//or
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_id);
tv.setText("random text");
```

Obviously other than saving one line of code I think the first option is better but I'd be glad if somebody who knows what he's talking about and could confirm that.
If the first option is better/faster, is it still worth using when i use the same view in one method lets say four times or is it better to assign view to variable at the start and then just use the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findViewById()` is an expensive call.

If you are operating on a view more than once, it is definitely best practice to store the view in a variable.

If you are operating on the view only once and never more than once, it doesn't matter. The memory or performance boost you might gain by not storing it in a variable is negligible.

Comment: Simple answer but exactly what I was looking for. Pretty much what i expected. Thanks